# fragment display wrongly on simulator

Tags: android, android-layout

I copy the same XML code to the activity, everything is fine.
But in this fragment, this happens, the display has some issue on the simulator, and I think the whole display move down a little bit.
The java code below is relating to this fragment.
activity_liuruiquan is the name of this fragment。
I think the crucial problem is when I AM USING nest fragment ,so infor will like on top of this layout(pic) just go white

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background1"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/applogo"
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="178dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:paddingStart="30dp"
            android:paddingEnd="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/applogo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/guidedog"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="@string/guidedog"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

```java
public class Liu extends Fragment {
    View LiuView;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LiuView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_liuruiquan, container, false);
        return LiuView;
    }


}
```

```java
 public void replaceFragment(Fragment somefragment) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction =  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, somefragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack("1");
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using fixed size on your views, that makes your screen not responsive to all screen sizes, that's because different phones got different screen sizes.

If you want your layout to be the same for every screen use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)/ [Relative layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative), and **DONT** use fixed size on your views.

Also - please avoid using nested views because that really makes your layout slower (it will keep getting slower depending on the number of your nested views that you are having)

Here is a simple example using constraintLayout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constrainLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[12]" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
```

It will look like this :

[image]

Note - this is just example that I gave, you can change your layout however you want. ConstraintLayout is really comfortable layout and I recommend to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in your XML code you have given the fixed size for layout. Unless it is required never use a fixed size for layout, it may vary with devices. you can use layout weight.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/applogo"
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="178dp"
            android:paddingStart="30dp"
            android:paddingEnd="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dummy_upasarga_logo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/guidedog"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

In your case use RelativeLayout.

Comment: Hey @Na Ran, I find your answer confusing. First, you say "Unless it is required never use a fixed size for layout" and then you are using a fixed size, for example `android:layout_height="178dp"`. Also, the use of `layout weight` will cause the layout to be slower because there are nested views and more calculations are required to render the layout. You can check my answer for a super simple solution.

Comment: Everyone doesn't have knowledge about Constraint Layout so layout weight is the only way. 

Comment: "Everyone doesn't have knowledge about Constraint Layout", well I (and many more) have knowledge about Constraint so I don't agree with what you just said. Beside - just because you don't know something doesn't make it not good.